Push Notification Not Displayed in Background (iOS) Despite Proper Setup
I am having trouble displaying push notifications when my iOS app is in the background or in sleep mode. Notifications work fine in the foreground, but they don’t show up in the background at all. I have verified my setup multiple times, including notification permissions, payload format, and background modes, but the issue persists.
What I Have Tried:
APNs Payload: The backend sends the following payload to APNs:
{
  "mediaDomain": "your_domain",
  "sendTime": "1633024800",
  "chatData": "chat_data_here",
  "time": "1633024800",
  "uuid": "unique_id",
  "senderPublicKey": "public_key",
  "receiverPublicKeyIdentifier": "receiver_id",
  "senderPublicKeyIdentifier": "sender_id",
  "version": "1",
  "chatID": "12345",
  "senderID": "67890",
  "receiverID": "54321",
  "isRetain": "false",
  "type": "chat_message",
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "palphone",
      "body": "You have one new message"
    },
    "sound": "default",
    "content-available": 1
  }
}


Notification Type: chat_message.
I expect this payload to display a notification with an alert and sound, but it doesn't work when the app is in the background.
AppDelegate Setup:
I’ve implemented the necessary methods in AppDelegate for handling push notifications:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let type = userInfo["type"] as? String, type == "chat_message" {
        // Process notification
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "New Message"
        content.body = "Check your messages."
        content.sound = .default
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: nil)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
    completionHandler(.newData)
}


Background Modes:
Remote notifications background mode is enabled in Signing & Capabilities.
Notification Permissions:
I am requesting notification permissions correctly in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
    if granted {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    } else {
        print("Notification permission denied.")
    }
}


Testing on Real Device:
I am testing on a real device, and notifications are not working in the background, but they work when the app is in the foreground.
What I Expected:
I expect to receive a visible notification with an alert and sound when the app is in the background, just like when it's in the foreground.
What Is Happening Instead:
No notification is displayed when the app is in the background or asleep. The didReceiveRemoteNotification method is not being called either.
My Environment:
Xcode version: 16.0.
iOS version: 18.0
Device: iPhone 16
Push Notification Service: Firebase / Custom APNs implementation
Additional Notes:
I’ve checked the logs from APNs, and the push notification is being delivered successfully to the device. It just isn’t being displayed.
content-available: 1 is included in the payload for background processing, but no local notification is being triggered.

Your APNS payload is wrong. Use below payload.
{
  "mediaDomain": "your_domain",
  "sendTime": "1633024800",
  "chatData": "chat_data_here",
  "time": "1633024800",
  "uuid": "unique_id",
  "senderPublicKey": "public_key",
  "receiverPublicKeyIdentifier": "receiver_id",
  "senderPublicKeyIdentifier": "sender_id",
  "version": "1",
  "chatID": "12345",
  "senderID": "67890",
  "receiverID": "54321",
  "isRetain": "false",
  "type": "chat_message",
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "palphone",
      "body": "You have one new message"
    },
    "sound": "default"
  }
}

What is the issue:
Your payload is acting as a silent push because of "content-available": 1.
Remove that key from the payload.
